# SAP link between operators working hours and production order

Tags: s4hana

I'm having trouble trying to found a link between production order and the worker (or the operator) that worked in that range of time.
In particular, my client has a custom tcode where he can see the working hours of the machine and the worker associated to the time range:

[image: TCODE]

In the field 'persNo' there is the code associated to the worker, in the fields start time and finish time the working hours linked to the worker.
I tried many tables like `so02`, `afvv`, and all the related tables to PP SAP module but I didn't find a field related to my needs.

Comment: Update: I solved this part. I found the tables!

Comment: So delete your question